# SQL запросы космические пираты

Tags: mysql, sql

```
Космические пираты все чаще атакуют грузовые и даже пассажирские суда. Органы охраны межпланетного правопорядка ведут статистику по нападениям в таблице attacks следующей структуры:

* planet_id (уникальный идентификатор планеты, которой принадлежит корабль);

* ship_name (название космического корабля);

* location (трехмерные координаты места нападения);

* dt (дата-время нападения).

Обобщенные данные по всем флотам в галактике хранятся в таблице space_fleet следующей структуры:

* id (уникальный идентификатор планеты);

* count_ships (общее число кораблей во флоте данной планеты).

Напишите SQL-запросы, позволяющие ответить на следующие вопросы:

A. Флоты скольких планет подверглись нападениям пиратов? (Было нападение хотя бы на один корабль).

B. Флоты скольких планет пока не пострадали? (Не было нападений ни на один корабль).

C. Флот какой планеты пострадал больше всего в процентном соотношении? (Нападениям подвергся максимальный процент кораблей флота).
```

Помогите с задачкой, пожалуйста. Я даже понять не могу, как связываются таблицы :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Таблицы связываются через planet_id и id соответственно. 
Дальше просто математическими операциями высчитываются все требуемые пункты

Comment: Какая связь? 1 - м, м - м, 1 - 1

Comment: В первой таблице поле planet_id не является уникальным, так как кораблей у одной планеты может быть >1. Например, planet_id == 24. И у нас есть 2 корабля: А и В. Значит, в первой таблице будет 2 записи: 24|А|location|dt и 24|В|location|dt. А во второй таблице 24|3. Это значит, что у планеты с id == 24 в наличии 3 корабля. Сопоставляя с первой таблицей, мы понимаем, что у этой планеты пострадало 66.67% флота

Comment: Запросы, думаю, стоит вам попробовать составить самому. А вот если уже не получится, то приложив свои попытки в пост, уже подскажут, где вы не правы

Comment: Все, понял логику, спасибо! С запросами думаю проблем не будет, но если что отпишусь, я на логике прям растерялся

Comment: Добрый вечер, все-таки возникли проблемы... Первые 2 запроса написал, последний тоже, но не понимаю, как вывести именно максимум:
`SELECT attacks.planet_id, ROUND(count(*) / space_fleet.count_ships * 100, 2)
AS Percent FROM attacks, space_fleet
WHERE space_fleet.id = attacks.planet_id
GROUP BY planet_id;`
Через MAX не получается, наверно не так применяю его, пытался в SELECT MAX указать

Comment: Разобрался: ORDER BY Percent DESC LIMIT 1;